# How to return distinct records in Rails when there is a has_many relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In a Rails 5 app, I have a table that is the table to link 2 other tables in a has many relationship. The two other tables are ‘group’ and ‘reflection’.

I'm trying to write a query that returns all the records from which a user is in.

```
@reflections = Groupreflectionlookup.where(group_id: @groups_user_is_in).reverse
```

However, when I do this, because the same reflection can exist in multiple groups, sometimes the same record is duplicated twice. See the image below:

How do I write a query such that while only has both records returned initially, but then only returns the distinct ‘reflection_ids”?

Group:

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :name, use: :slugged

  has_many :groupreflectionlookups
  has_many :reflections, :through => :groupreflectionlookups
end
```

Reflection

```
class Reflection < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user

    has_many :comments

    has_many :userreflectionlookups
    has_many :users, :through => :userreflectionlookups

    has_many :groupreflectionlookups
    has_many :groups, :through => :groupreflectionlookups


end
```

Part of schema

```
  create_table "groups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.integer "user_admin_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string "slug"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.index ["slug"], name: "index_groups_on_slug", unique: true
  end

  create_table "reflections", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.text "reflection"
    t.integer "user_id"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.text "thorns"
  end
```

[image]

Comment: Would you mind sharing with us your 2 models?

Comment: I included the 2 models in the post now.

Comment: Ok, so what do you want your result to be different from your current https://i.stack.imgur.com/pqkXc.png?

Comment: Think I figured it out! @reflections = Groupreflectionlookup.select(:reflection_id).distinct.where(group_id: @groups_user_is_in).reverse

Comment: Ok, great you found the answer.

Answer (score 1):

It might be more meaningful to define the `distinct` clause on the `has_many` relationship itself, eg.

```
has_many :groups, -> { distinct }, through: :groupreflectionlookups
```

Answer (score 0):

@reflections = Groupreflectionlookup.select(:reflection_id).distinct.where(group_id: @groups_user_is_in).reverse